# long url rewriting with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

here is my url

http://www.mydomain.com/browse.php?type=3d&subtype=started&ref=foo

how an i convert this to...

http://www.mydomain.com/browse/3d/start/foo

i have seen many questions on stackoverflow but none have given and related ans to my prob...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^browse/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ browse.php?type=$1&subtype=$2&ref=$3
```

I've left the trailing slash as optional.